# Implementing repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

As per [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) on asp.net, it shows this code:

```
using System;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
        private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
        private GenericRepository<Course> courseRepository;

        public GenericRepository<Department> DepartmentRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.departmentRepository == null)
                {
                    this.departmentRepository = new GenericRepository<Department>(context);
                }
                return departmentRepository;
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<Course> CourseRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.courseRepository == null)
                {
                    this.courseRepository = new GenericRepository<Course>(context);
                }
                return courseRepository;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to write code every time I want add a new database table?  For instance, if I wanted to add a StudentsRepository, I would have to do this (?):

```
private GenericRepository<Student> studentRepository;

public GenericRepository<Student> StudentRepository
{
    get
    {

        if (this.studentRepository == null)
        {
            this.studentRepository = new GenericRepository<Student>(context);
        }
        return studentRepository;
    }
}
```

What if my database has 50 tables?  Do I have to write this code for all 50!?

Comment: Can you imagine trying to maintain a single repository class if your database had 50 tables?

Comment: So, your answer is yes, I will have to maintain all this additional code in order to facilitate repository pattern?

Comment: I'm sure there are people better placed to answer this, but in my experience having worked in systems with dozens of tables I'd use an ORM tool (e.g. NHibernate) where every table is represented by at least a class. It's a lot of overhead but you have the granular control you need to manage it correctly.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework but I thought Repository pattern was supposed to be an additional abstraction layer.  Just not sure if I am thinking about this right...

Comment: The Repository pattern abstracts the developer from the internals of repository implementation, i.e. saving to a file / database / somewhere in the cloud, but you still need something that represents the database or whatever you're saving to, which in your case is managed by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is "yes", the unit of work should contain properties to access all possible repositories.

If it bothers you to write code, create a T4 template and let the class be generated automatically.

Comment: It's not a huge both the write the initial code, just maintaining this larger code base for this seemingly redundant layer of abstraction!

Comment: I don't get it - the repository is redundant? You don't have to use it. There is NO way of simplyfying this in C# except for making it easier, e.g. by using T4.

Comment: I do have to use it since it's a project requirement.  I don't see how this is going to help anything, but since I have to implement it, I am trying to understand it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, you lack the rationale behind repositories then. The shortest story is: coding against repositories allow you to change data access layer, for example you could possibly switch to another ORM without changing upper layers code. Without repositories and with coding directly against EF, changing EF to another ORM somewhere in future would be nearly impossible or at least very, very tedious.

Comment: I have known that but it seems like a lot of overhead for something [switching from EF] that will probably never happen since EF is the premier ORM for .NET.

Comment: You hit the nail in the head. If switching from EF to another data layer is never gonna happen, there is probably no need for repositories. Notice that EF's data context IS a repository itself! What you do then, is you wrap it with another repository. However, a lot of people (including myself) will tell you that this MAKES sense, data access technologies tend to change faster than your business code.

Comment: So is the `Student` entity from `GenericRepository<Student> studentRepository;` supposed to come from EF or am I supposed to write all the entities as well?  For instance, if I created a new Students table in my database, I would have to generate it in EF, then ceate a new class called `Student`, and finally, create a new `StudentRepostory`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37470/discussion-between-wiktor-zychla-and-user1477388)